# What workflows help when using Photo Stream to import from iOS to Aperture?

Tags: iphone, photo-stream, aperture, camera

When I take a picture on my iPhone, the photo is going to PhotoStream and to Camera Roll.

My way of importing the pictures to my Mac was just to go in the PhotoStream folder of Aperture, and copy the pictures into some particular project, that way, the picture is "disconnected" from PhotoStream and will stay forever in my mac.

But that means I now have 1000+ pictures in my iPhone, and the backup to iCloud is not working anymore.

My best stab at a workflow is to manually import the whole iPhone in Aperture and then deal with duplicates. This works miserably when I forget and re-import photos and duplicate a whole bunch of imported pictures from PhotoStream. Can the detection of duplicates where the ones that were already imported via PhotoStream from Aperture be relied upon?

What is the usual workflow that avoids this main problem of duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the photos from the Phone after you've processed them in Aperture? Seems like the obvious thing. Tap the Share Button and then select the pics you want to delete and then tap delete.

Comment: That can't be the only way, why would one delete the pictures one by one (or a few at a time) every time ? I guess there's some more intuitive ways ...

Comment: The problem is you can't use Aperture to clear the phone as you're not using the standard import pane in it. So now your options for clearing the phone are either with the phone or Image Capture (in your Applications Folder)